# Cross tab conditional color based on values in Summary Field

Tags: birt, crosstab

I have designed cross tab to display values like USERID, NAME, STATUS and SCENARIO. The Scenario is displayed in cross tab using summary field in data cube. I need to change the color of the userid field based on the below condition

```
if scenario1 == 1 || scenario2 == 1 then USERID is RED 
if scenario3 == 1 || scenario4 == 1 then USERID is ORANGE 
 and so on
```

I tried to achieve this using highlights on USERID however the below condition does not bring any error however the color still remains the same

```
if(data["scenario"]==1){
     1;
     }
     else{
      0;
       }
```

Below is the screen shot of the report output 
[image: report output]

Updated image of Highlights
[image: Highlights]

Layout screen shot [image: layout]
Updated condition [image: Updated in condition]

Comment: Could you add the highlights screen shot? Do you want to add color on all the line or just on the cell? If it the cell, please, be sure that you select the cell and not the USERID data binding (was my error first)

Comment: @FannyV I have added the image as requested . The requirement is to color the USERID field alone . I tried to do it in cell however no luck

Comment: Why are you using data? That should be a row, I think. But, could you try : in the condition : "data["senario"] ==1" and "Is True" in the drop down list ? Be sure to select the cell and not the data

Comment: @FannyV I tried the condition you have mentioned and it did not work. I tried row as well however I am confused on the condition as the scenario is in the summary field in data cube. I have attached the screen shot of my layout page. The USERID color should change based on the values in Scenario (highlighted in RED). Hence if I use row instead of data then the condition : row._outer["scenario"] ==1 and "IsTrue" correct ?

Comment: no you're right, it's data :) I'm trying to reproduce your cross table

Comment: let's try in condition "data["scenario"] == "scenario1" && data["scenario_Group3..."] == 1" with "Is True" in the drop down list. I don't have the complet name of "scenario_Group3... " so complete it.

Comment: @FannyV I have tried and it didnt work, attached screen shot, thanks!

Comment: Do you agree that data["scenario"] print "scenario1", "scenario2",... and data["scenario_Group3..."] print "1" or "". Oh wait ! data ["scenario_Group3..."] is String or number? Try : "1" not 1

Comment: @FannyV no I tried that already it does not work